# sort an array of strings, using another array of strings to determine the order

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting

I am trying to sort an array of strings, using another array of strings to determine the order for the first. For the function below, I modified a typical sort function. It works fine I think except when it tries to handle arrays with multiple instances of a first letter; then it thinks they are the *first* instance of that letter in the variable `orderRequired` (although they are not always). Consequently it groups them side by side instead of where I want them.

```
var orderRequired = ['b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'b', 'e'];
//note orderRequired.indexOf('b') !== orderRequired.lastIndexOf('b');
var arr = ['apple', 'banana', 'biscuit', 'cabbage', 'doughnut', 'eclair'];
var myVar = sortThese(orderRequired, arr);
console.log(myVar); 
// gives: ["banana", "biscuit", "cabbage", "apple", "doughnut", "eclair"]
// but I want: ["banana", "cabbage", "apple", "doughnut", "biscuit", "eclair"]

function sortThese(ordReq, arr){
    return arr.sort(function sortFunction(a,b){
        var indexA = ordReq.indexOf(a[0]);
        var indexB = ordReq.indexOf(b[0]);
        if(indexA < indexB) {
            return -1;
        }else if(indexA > indexB) {
            return 1;
        }else{
            return 0;       
        }
    });
}
```

For cases where it compares 'banana' and 'biscuit', whichever is the earliest instance in `arr` is also to be the earliest instance in the result. In the array above there are two instances of 'b' words, and for now I am happy with a solution that can sort this array. A perfect solution though could perhaps sort 3 or more instances. For example,

```
var orderRequiredPartTwo = ['b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'b', 'b', 'e']; // this has 3 'b's
var arrPartTwo = ['banoffee', 'apple', 'banana', 'biscuit', 'cabbage', 'doughnut', 'eclair'];
var myVarPartTwo = sortThese(orderRequiredPartTwo, arrPartTwo);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for alphabetical order in arrPartTwo?  Is that the end goal?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do here. What exactly are the semantics of the values in the `orderRequired` array?

Comment: @BrandenKeck no not alphabetical. I want to rearrange arr so it's first letters assume the same order as orderRequired. Also, anything with PartTwo is a more advanced version of the question, so it can be ignored in the early stages.

Comment: @Paul Okay I have an idea I will post as answer if I can coherently organize my thoughts here

Comment: @Paul nevermind, foxdonut's answer looks very good

Comment: @Pointy no semantics required. foxdonut has solved it. Thanks.

Comment: @BrandenKeck thanks for your input :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to go through the array, find the index in the orderRequired array, use the index to build the sorted array, and null out the index in orderRequired:

```js
var orderRequired = ['b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'b', 'b', 'e'];
var arr = ['banoffee', 'apple', 'banana', 'biscuit', 'cabbage', 'doughnut', 'eclair'];

var sortThese = function(orderReq, arr) {
  var result = [];
  
  for (var i = 0, t = arr.length; i < t; i++) {
    var item = arr[i];
    var index = orderReq.indexOf(item[0]);
    result[index] = item;
    orderReq[index] = null;
  }
  
  return result;
};
var sorted = sortThese(orderRequired, arr);
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(sorted);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: That's beautiful, perfect, thank you so much foxdonut! :D

Comment: This answer is great. I sandboxed it, and it works just fine. I encountered a weird bug/conflict when I integrated it with some other functions, inside a loop full of such arrays. It was leaving the latter instance of the multi-instances blank, i.e. ''. I 'fixed' it by changing 'return result' to 'return arr'. I know.. that shouldn't work, right? I am completely baffled, 'cause it's working flawlessly :/

Comment: @Paul no, that definitely will not work. If it seems to be, that means you've changed something else.

Comment: @Pointy, of course you are right. I did change something else earlier (1 day) in another function and it had the unexpected effect of ordering them correctly. However my old sort function was then undoing the sorting, so I didn't notice the win, hehe. I guess it just means things will run that much faster with no sorting to do. Thanks! :)